# Looking for Ways to Improve RecyclerView Preformance

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-recyclerview, lag

I have a pretty complex view with many moving parts in a RecyclerView with an adapter that takes care of showing two different view types and "hiding" objects from the list in order to create "collapsing" comments. The code is all working and it displays fine, but it gets extremely laggy on flings downward or upward, and I really can't find a way to simplify my code and/or views. Here is a link to all the code and views

Comment.xml (view)
https://github.com/ccrama/Slide/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/comment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:clipChildren="false"


    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/card_background"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/padd"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dots"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="?attr/activity_background"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/dot"
                        layout="@layout/dot" />


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/side"
                    layout="@layout/dot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/background"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"

                    android:paddingTop="8dp"

                    >


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            >

                            <include
                                android:id="@+id/children"
                                layout="@layout/commentnumber"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                                android:layout_height="16dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" />


                            <com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/author"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:text="ccrama"

                                    android:textColor="?attr/font"
                                    android:textSize="?attr/font_commenttitle"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"

                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/score"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"

                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:text="+49"
                                    android:textColor="?attr/font"
                                    android:textSize="?attr/font_commentinfo"

                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/time"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"

                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:text="4 hours ago"

                                    android:textColor="?attr/font"

                                    android:textSize="?attr/font_commentinfo" />

                                <include
                                    android:id="@+id/gild"
                                    layout="@layout/gilded"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"

                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp" />

                                <include
                                    android:id="@+id/flairbubble"
                                    layout="@layout/flair"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"

                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinned"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/pinned" />

                                <include
                                    android:id="@+id/you"
                                    layout="@layout/you"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"

                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinned"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/pinned" />

                                <include
                                    android:id="@+id/op"
                                    layout="@layout/op"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="16dp"

                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pinned"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/pinned" />
                            </com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <me.ccrama.redditslide.ActiveTextView
                            android:id="@+id/content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingBottom="16dp"

                            android:textColor="?attr/font"
                            android:textSize="?attr/font_commentbody" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/more"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/more"


                android:tint="?attr/tint" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/downvote"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="12dp"

                android:src="@drawable/downvoteicon"
                android:tint="?attr/tint" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/upvote"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/upvoteicon"

                android:tint="?attr/tint" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="12dp"

                android:src="@drawable/reply"
                android:tint="?attr/tint" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/replyArea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/replyLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="?attr/tint"
                android:hint="Reply"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoEnterAction"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/font"
                android:textColorHint="?attr/font" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/discard"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="4dp"

                    android:text="DISCARD"
                    android:textColor="?attr/font"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/send"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="4dp"

                    android:text="SUBMIT"
                    android:textColor="?attr/font"

                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/innersend2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                android:alpha=".56"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:weightSum="8">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imagerep"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/image"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/link"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/link"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bold"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"

                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/bold"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/italics"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/italics"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bulletlist"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/bullets"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/numlist"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"

                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/numbers"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/quote"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"

                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/quotes"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/size"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"

                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/fontsizedarker"
                    android:tint="?attr/tint" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, it is a pretty complicated view with 3 main parts. The top "comment" area which is always visible, a menu which visibility is toggled, and a reply area where visibility is rarely used, but can still be toggled.

[Here is a link to the adapter](https://github.com/ccrama/Slide/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/ccrama/redditslide/Adapters/CommentAdapter.java)

[Here is a link to the view the adapter is in](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccrama/Slide/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_verticalcontenttoolbar.xml) (might be helpful!)

I'm hoping that the issue is somewhat simple, but I really can't figure out how to make the code any simpler.

Steps I've taken to fix the lag:
Remove all the code in the comment adapter, still noticeable lag
Remove menu and reply area from the view, improvement but still slow.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: here's a video of the lag in question https://vid.me/kxrC

Comment: I think you'll need to simplify all those nested linearlayouts..  Maybe use a relativelayout or gridview instead. Maybe have a custom view for the sets of images...

Comment: Hmm interesting. Didn't think of using a RelativeLayout instead!

Comment: Yeah thats a pretty complex view hierarchy. I'm going to guess that the FlowLayout doesnt do any view caching (like what an adapter implementation does), so all of those child re-positioning is happening constantly on scrolls

Comment: Interesting. I'll try to change them to recyclerviews and see how my framerate goes!